# Rego: Given a list of regex and a list of strings create a set of all strings that don't match any of the regex

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I have a list of strings and I want to remove each string from the list that matches any of the regex patterns from another list. I have solved it this way, however, I know there is a better way to do so. For example:

Regex_list := ["^reg\ex1", "/^\d+$/", "^Apple"]

String_list := ["Apple", "Banana", "Pair" "12345"]

Want - {Banana, Pair}

I don't know my regex, but for this example lets say Apple and 12345 match the last 2 on the regex list. I want to have a list only containing Banana and Pair.

My take:

`string_list := input.string_list[_]`

`match := {x | x := string_list; regex.match(data.regex_list[_], x)}` --> {Apple, 12345}

`dont_match := string_list - match` --> {"Banana", "Pair"}

Answer (score 1):

I think that is the best way. Alternatively you could use a rule to build a set of matches, but the principle would be the same.

```
matches[s] {
    r := [`^reg\ex1`, `^\d+$`, `^Apple`][_]
    s := ["Apple", "Banana", "Pair", "12345"][_]
    
    regex.match(r, s)
}
```